# PHP preg_match: Match everything except string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to be able to extract segments of a full file path and name to insert into a data base. To do this I am using preg_match in PHP. I am also giving each segment a name from within the pattern so that the array of matches is an associative one. Here is an example:

```
    $subject = 'c:/files/uk/kent/ashford/12345_Joe_Blogs_20120202120000.pdf';
    $pattern = '/[\/\\\\](?<country>.*)[\/\\\\](?<county>.*)[\/\\\\](?<town>.*)[\/\\\\](?<id>.*)_(?<first_name>.*)_(?<last_name>.*)_(?<datetime>.*)\.(?<file_extension>pdf)/';
    preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
    foreach($matches as $key => $match)
    {
        if(is_numeric($key))
            unset($matches[$key]);
    }
    print_r($matches);
```

Which creates:

```
    Array
    (
        [country] => files/uk
        [county] => kent
        [town] => ashford
        [id] => 12345
        [first_name] => Joe
        [last_name] => Blogs
        [datetime] => 20120202120000
        [file_extension] => pdf
     )
```

My problem is that country includes all folders preceding the one I want. I only want the 'uk' part and not 'files/uk'. So I need to know how to match everything except '/' or '\'. The 'c:/files' can be anything pre-set in the configurations so I don't want to include that or any other PHP variable in the pattern.

I have looked this up in Google and alike but I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to modify the tricky Regex, I recommend keeping your existing code and using  the [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function.

Try this:

```
echo basename($matches['country']);
//outputs "uk"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change regex to:

```
$pattern = '/[\/\\\\](?<folder>.*)[\/\\\\](?<country>.*)[\/\\\\](?<county>.*)[\/\\\\](?<town>.*)[\/\\\\](?<id>.*)_(?<first_name>.*)_(?<last_name>.*)_(?<datetime>.*)\.(?<file_extension>pdf)/';
```

Then you have folder *member* in array, which you can use or discard later.

Answer (score 0):

you cane try this :

```
$pattern = '/[\/\\\\](.*)[\/\\\\](?<country>.*)[\/\\\\](?<county>.*)[\/\\\\](?<town>.*)[\/\\\\](?<id>.*)_(?<first_name>.*)_(?<last_name>.*)_(?<datetime>.*)\.(?<file_extension>pdf)/';
```

its work dear..! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try being more specific about what you do and don't want to match:

```
'%(?x)
[/\\\\](?P<country>[^_./\\\\]+)
[/\\\\](?P<county>[^_./\\\\]+)
[/\\\\](?P<town>[^_/\\\\]+)
[/\\\\](?P<id>[^_./\\\\]+)
_(?P<first_name>[^_./\\\\]+)
_(?P<last_name>[^_./\\\\]+)
_(?P<datetime>[^_./\\\\]+)
\.(?P<file_extension>pdf)
%'
```

I'm assuming you never want more than one directory to appear in any group, and that the directory/file names will never include underscores or periods other than the ones you're explicitly matching.